# Ruby on Rails - How to pass hash parameter to a partial view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

'shared/subscription' %>

To call this partial view:

```
<% form_for(:subscription, :url => city_subscriptions_path(@city)) do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :city_id, :value => @city.id %>
  <%= form.text_field :email, :size => 30 %>
  <%= form.submit "Email Me" %>
<% end %>
```

Since I am using this partial view on different places, how do I alter the caller so it will pass a hash for the `form_for` helper? So it would be like this when the helper is called:

```
<% form_for(:subscription, :url => city_subscriptions_path(@city), :html => {:id => 'main_input' }) do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :city_id, :value => @city.id %>
  <%= form.text_field :email, :size => 30 %>
  <%= form.submit "Email Me" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/subscription", :locals => {:foo => "bar", :foofoo => ["bar", "bar"]}
```

In your partial view, use them:

```
<%= foo #this outputs "bar" %>
<%= foofoo.to_s %>
```

Comment: `@foo` or just `foo`? I suppose that just `foo`.

Comment: Thanks but I tried to retrieve the variable using 
    `<% form_for(:subscription, :url => city_subscriptions_path(@city), :html => {:id => @form_id} ) do |form| %>`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: so you want to pass form_id into the form from outside the partial? `render :partial => "something", :locals => {:form_id => "abc"}` and `form_for (:subscription, :url => city_subscriptions_path(@city), :html => {:id => form_id } ) do |form|`